# On SQL Insert, during the transaction, how do I get the value of another field in this new row to copy to another field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
FORMS
----
form_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT id_generator(),
...
...
form_pretty_url character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT 'form-'::*GET_FORM_ID*
```

The id_generator function is copied from here:
http://rob.conery.io/2014/05/29/a-better-id-generator-for-postgresql/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION id_generator(OUT result bigint) AS $$
DECLARE
    our_epoch bigint := 1314220021721;
    seq_id bigint;
    now_millis bigint;
    shard_id int := 5;
BEGIN
    SELECT nextval('insta5.table_id_seq') % 1024 INTO seq_id;
    SELECT FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM clock_timestamp()) * 1000) INTO now_millis;
    result := (now_millis - our_epoch) << 23;
    result := result | (shard_id << 10);
    result := result | (seq_id);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Calling last_value or currval(), lastval() or any other available function doesn't return what I'd like.

The database being used is PostgreSQL.

Comment: From the title it sounds as though you are looking for a trigger, but your question makes no mention of this.

Comment: So it HAS to be done via a trigger?  It can't be done via some function built-into Postgres?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want to happen. Rewrite your question to provide table definitions, the operation you perform and what you want to happen. Provide sample data. Tell us your PG version.

Comment: Do you use database sharding with up to 1,024 inserts per millisecond per shard? If not, then forget about Rob Conery's solution. Apart from being over-the-top for 99.99% of any database setup, it is also not nearly as efficient as it pretends to be.

Answer (score 1):

The default value for a column cannot reference another column. There's a specific error message for that:

```
=> create table tst(i int, j int default i);
ERROR:  cannot use column references in default expression
```

You may use a BEFORE INSERT trigger to achieve the desired result.
As there is a `NOT NULL` constraint on that column, it still needs a non-null default value, because the constraint is checked and must be valid before the trigger is run.

Change of definition:

```
 form_pretty_url character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Trigger example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigfunc() RETURNS TRIGGER as $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.form_pretty_url = '' THEN
     NEW.form_pretty_url := 'form-' || NEW.form_id::text; 
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END $$ language plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER trigname BEFORE INSERT  ON tablename
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigfunc();
```

Comment: Haha!  Thanks, Daniel.  That's exactly what I went with this morning!